# Declare an interface where all properties conform to a type, WITHOUT widening the interface

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a way of declaring that an interface's properties adhere to a particular type, *without* widening that interface.

For example:

```
export interface ServiceDeclaration {
  [key: string]: (params?: any) => Promise<any>;
}

interface MyService extends ServiceDeclaration {
  doThing(params?: { id: string }): Promise<string>;
}
```

So far so good. This will assert that all properties in `MyService` are async functions w/ at most one parameter.

However this also results in `MyService` is also widened to include the index type from `ServiceDeclaration`. For example:

```
// This should result in an error of 'notAThing' being a key of
// MyService. Instead it resolves to (params?: any) => Promise<any>
export type Foo = Pick<MyService, 'notAThing'>;
```

Is there a clean way of asserting that `MyService` adheres to `ServiceDeclaration` without widening its type? And, can it be done without jumping through awkward hoops (like passing it through a faux function, or exporting another type)?

---

One approach that *does* work, but is pretty awkward, is to add an extra type assertion (and export it as another unused type):

```
export type ServiceDeclaration<TKey extends string = string> = {
  [Key in TKey]: (params?: any) => Promise<any>;
}

export type IsValidServiceDeclaration<TService extends Record<keyof TService, (params?: any) => Promise<any>>> = TService;

interface MyService {
  doThing(params?: { id: string }): Promise<string>;
  doAnotherThing(params?: { id: string }): string;
}

export type MyServiceIsValid = IsValidServiceDeclaration<MyService>
```

I'm looking for something better than this.

Comment: Don't think you can do better, I would just point out you don't need all the extra ceremony of `MySevice` and `MyServiceIsValid` you can just do : `export type MyService = IsValidServiceDeclaration<{
  doThing(params?: { id: string }): Promise<string>;
}>`

Comment: Huh! that actually may be the way to go. Seems to be the most concise option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export type ServiceDeclaration<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (params?: any) => Promise<any>;
};

interface MyService extends ServiceDeclaration<MyService> {
  doThing(params?: { id: string }): Promise<string>;
}

export type Foo = Pick<MyService, 'notAThing'>; // Type '"notAThing"' does not satisfy the constraint '"doThing"'.
```